# What makes pink salt pink?

Tags: salt

What are some of the names of chemical compounds (minerals our what not) which make the healthy (sandless) pink salt pink?

Comment: There seem to be at least [three products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pink_salt) that can be called "pink salt"... can you be more specific about which of them you're talking about?

Comment: If you're talking about Himalayan Pink Salt, this question has already been answered [here](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/64789/why-is-himalayan-salt-pink).

Comment: I think that would be Himalayan salt, since it comes from ancient mountains. Thanks.

Comment: Wikipedia is your friend https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhalite